# How to setup CLion for ROS remotely?

Tags: ros

I know how to set up `CMake` and `Toolchain` remotely using ssh through [official wiki](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/ros-setup-tutorial.html).

Does anyone know how to configure a remote `ROS` environment in CLion?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any update on this?